# Prove any $n>2$ DE doesn't hold Poincaré-Bendixson theorem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

How can I build a differential equation to show that Poincaré-Bendixson theorem doesn't hold for $n≥3$ ? Is it easy to take any D.E with $n=3$ and prove it? More specifically, can you give me a detailed explanation to prove it?

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747480/dynamics-of-a-three-dimensional-system/1748044#1748044

Comment: Sorry, I don't really seem to get it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you draw the phase portrait of that system you surely get ideas on how a counterexample could be constructed, say in a ball.